# Unicode e UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, unicode

Qual a diferença entre Unicode e UTF-8? São a mesma codificação ou uma é derivada da outra?

Comment: Unicode pode ser implementado com diversas codificações de carácter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings?wprov=sfsi1 ; UTF8 é uma dessas implementações, sendo compatível com o ASCII

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unicode** pode se referir:

- ao conjunto de caracteres padrão universal - *UCS (Universal Character Set)* - definido e mantido pelo [Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org/)
- ou aos *codepoints* que identificam os caracteres no *UCS*.

**UTF** significa *Unicode ou (UCS) Transformation Format*, que é como caracteres *unicode* são representados na memória do computador ou transmitidos.

Para realmente entender a diferença entre **unicode** e **UTF-8** é necessário entender bem os seguintes conceitos.

1. #### Caracter abstrato

   Um caracter abstrato é um **[ideal platônico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoria_das_ideias)** de um **elemento *fundamental* de texto**.

   O *ideal platônico* refere-se, por exemplo, ao conceito de que *R* é igual **R** ou a qualquer outra representação da letra R.

   Já a questão de **elemento *fundamental* de texto** é mais complicada, por exemplo **ç** pode ser entendido como um único caractere ou como a composição de dois: **c** e **¸**.

   Parte do trabalho da *Unicode Consortium* está em identificar esses elementos fundamentais. Veja abaixo exemplos da relação entre elementos (não fundamentais) de texto e caracteres.

   [image: Relação entre elementos de textos e caracteres]
2. #### *codepoint*

   Uma vez definidos os caracteres a *Unicode Consortium* define *codepoints* para esses caracteres. Esses *codepoints* são **identificadores** e **NÃO têm, necessariamente, relação com como os caracteres são armazenados na memória**, eles são uma abstração que permite identificar todos os caracteres mapeados facilmente.

   Esses *codepoints* também são comumente referidos como *Unicodes* e são representados como **U+0041** ou **\u0041** (Letra **A**)

   Como é possível ver abaixo um caracter abstrato pode ser representado por um ou mais caracteres *unicode*

   [image: relação entre caracteres abstratos e codepoints]
3. #### *code unit*

   Se refere a como os *codepoints* são armazenados na memória ou transmitidos. O UTF-8 utiliza *code units* de 8 bits para armazenar os caracteres *Unicode*. Dependendo do caracter o UTF-8 usa de 1 a 4 *code units*, por exemplo, **A** usa uma *code unit*, **Ω** duas e **𐎄** quatro.

   A imagem abaixo mostra como os diferentes formatos codificam os mesmos caracteres. No UTF-32 o *codepoint* é igual ao *code unit*, o mesmo não vale para os demais formatos e a conversão de *codepoint* para *code units* não é óbvia.

   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Informações e imagens retiradas de [*Unicode Standard Version 10.0 - Core Specification*](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/ch02.pdf#G13708)